# How to repair cylinder mesh with misplaced vertices?

Tags: mesh, workflow, vertices

I realized, for the first time, I now have the skill to visualize and manifest a 3D object of some complexity!

Do you see this rocket?

[image: image of rocket with messed up vertices]

It looks pretty cool.  But, nobody would put this thing on the launchpad with an screw-up like this on it.


This thing started life as a cylinder, but and was then highly processed.  But, I don't know an efficient or elegant way of healing this.  I *could* do it manually - vertex by vertex - but there must be a better way!


Thanks for any help in advance....

Answer (score 6):

If your rocket is symmetrical you could delete the upper half of the vertices, add a mirror modifier and apply (for an easier selection, I would isolate the tip).

[image: mirror modifier]

You are right, Gunslinger, here is a picture:

Comment: Some screenshots should be helpful.

Comment: Good solution, but note that this will not work if the distortions occur on both sides of the mesh.

Answer (score 3):

You could also select the vertices and remove them.

Select the loop <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>RMB</kbd>

[image]

<kbd>Space</kbd> for search enter gridfill

- Use the *Knife-Tool* <kbd>K</kbd> to add edges.

[image]

- Last step would be to align the edges circular,

<kbd>W</kbd> shows the *Specials Menu* select LoopTools / Circle.

Note: you would need to enable the *Loop Tools* in the *User Preferences* addon section first.

[image]

Repaired result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to delete the messed up face loops and then regenerate them.

1. Select the broken edge rings with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd>:

   [image]
2. Delete them with <kbd>Delete</kbd> or <kbd>X</kbd>*> Vertices*:

   [image]
3. Select the edges around the gaps (again with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd>) and press <kbd>W</kbd>*> Bridge Edge Loops*:

   [image]
4. Tweak the settings in the *Redo menu* as desired:

   [image]
5. Repeat steps 3-4 for any other gaps.